# (GTM) Issue with AdBlock detection fb pixel standard event parameter

Tags: jquery, facebook, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

I managed to fire a FB standard event when AdBlock is enabled/disabled. However I need to have the honeypot and dataLayer push script hardcoded in the page to make it work. When adding both the fake "ad_status.js" file and dataLayer push script as tags in GTM, the parameter sent to the standard event is always set as "true", even when AdBlock is disabled.

Here is what I have:

1 js file "ad_status.js" containing the following:

```
var e=document.createElement('div'); e.id='NGjRPgxAQCMZ'; 
e.style.display='none'; document.body.appendChild(e);
```

1 Data Layer variable "AdBlocked" whose data variable name is "blocked":

- Variable type: Data Layer variable
- Variable name: blocked

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxJCa.png)

**1 custom HTML tag called "AdbLock detection":**

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var d = document.createElement('script');
    d.src = '//www.mydomain.com/ad_status.js';
    document.head.appendChild(d);
  })();
</script>
```

- Fires on All Pages

**1 custom HTML tag that push an event when AdBlock is enabled or disabled:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(checkAds());
        function checkAds() {
            if (document.getElementById('NGjRPgxAQCMZ') != undefined) {
                document.write("<script>dataLayer.push({'event':'adBlock','blocked':'false'});</sc" + "ript>");
            } else {
                document.write("<script>dataLayer.push({'event':'adBlock','blocked':'true'});</sc" + "ript>");
            }
        }
// ]]></script>
```

- Fires on All Pages
- tag sequencing is set so this second tag fires after the first one.

**1 custom HTML tag with the fb standard event:**

```
<script>
fbq('track', 'AdBlock', {
enabled: {{AdBlocked}}
});
</script>
```

- Fires when following "Custom Event" is met:

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhrJL.png)

Any help would be really pleased!

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you please add your `ad_status.js` and your variable `AdBlocked`. I think it is possible to achieve your goal in easier way

Comment: Hello @VictorLeontyev ! I added the content of ad_status.js and the content of the AdBlocked variable (also available in screenshot) in the main post. If you have something easier, that would be even better of course! :) Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need so many tags. All what you need is:

- Add `ad_status.js` to your website root folder
- Create custom HTML tag with `PageView` trigger

Html code:

```
<script>
    var ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT = true;
    (function() {
        function checkAds(){
            var blocked = document.getElementById('NGjRPgxAQCMZ') == null;
            fbq('track', 'AdBlock', {
                enabled: blocked
            });
        }     
        var d = document.createElement('script');
        d.src = '/ad_status.js';
        document.head.appendChild(d);
        d.addEventListener('load', function() {
            ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT = false;
            checkAds()
        });
        setTimeout( function() {
            if (ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT)
            {
                checkAds();
            }
        },1000);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: You are genius. Working perfectly and just one tag needed, thank you!